# Why This Query Breaks?

Tags: php, url

I have this URL-

```
http://localhost/app_demo/sample.php?jsonRequest={"GenInfo":{"type":"Request","appname":"XXX","appversion":"1.0.0"},"searchDish":{"userId":"295","dishName":"","est":"Pizza &amp; Wings","location":"","type":"","priceRange":"","deviceos":"value","deviceId":"<UDID>","deviceType":"value","pageNo":"1"}}
```

when I hit this URL and print

```
print_r($_REQUEST['jsonRequest']);
```

string print only upto

```
{"GenInfo":{"type":"Request","appname":"XXX","appversion":"1.0.0"},"searchDish":{"userId":"295","dishName":"","est":"2 Pizza
```

I search the net but did not get the answer.What is solution for this?
please help,
thanks.

Comment: DON'T USE `$_REQUEST` specify `$_POST` or `$_GET`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A query string is normally composed of key/value pairs, the start of a query string is the question mark (?), and then all pairs are separated with an ampersand (&). Having an ampersand in your value is like starting a new parameter.

However, this is not the right way to do this. You shouldn't put JSON in the query string.

If you **really** must have an ampersand in the query string, use **%26** and not **&amp**. %26 which is the hex value for the ampersand.

Answer (score 2):

You should make a POST request instead of a GET request:

- Encoding collisions
- URI length limit

Answer (score 1):

The character "&" is the problem, because it is reserved. (is the query string params separator)
You must "[urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)" your string before use it on your GET request. So characters like & are converted. But as jValdron point it you shouldn't put JSON in the query string, but you can do it.

So you urlencode the string:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/app_demo/sample.php?jsonRequest=';
$jsonRequest = urlencode('{"GenInfo":{"type":"Request","appname":"XXX","appversion":"1.0.0"},"searchDish":{"userId":"295","dishName":"","est":"Pizza &amp; Wings","location":"","type":"","priceRange":"","deviceos":"value","deviceId":"<UDID>","deviceType":"value","pageNo":"1"}}');
$url .= $jsonRequest;
```

And then you [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
print_r(urldecode($_REQUEST['jsonRequest']));
```

**Again, you shouldn't put JSON in the query string.**